# Grails GSP Screen Width

Tags: grails, responsive

I need to check the screen size to change a component.
Without knowing the best way, i try use javascript in

```html
<g:if test="${javascript($(window).width() > 768)}">
  //COMPONENT
</g:if>
<g:else>
  //OTHER COMPONENT
</g:else>
```

Anyone can help me saying the best way to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing that `COMPONENT` is in your example it's difficult to offer a solid solution.

However, the major issue you are facing is that you are trying to mix server-side and client-side evaluation which you can't do. GSP is evaluated at the server level and doesn't have access to the browser's DOM to get things such as `window.width`.

One possible solution is to submit the `window.width` with the request to the GSP as a request variable so that you can evaluate that using the GSP.

Answer (score 0):

@Joshua is right, you are mixing and matching client and server side code. You could use a plugin https://github.com/mathifonseca/grails-browser-detection which is a nice wrapper around the httprequest so you can check if you are communicating with a desktop or mobile browser. 
But normally this would be done using stylesheet (@see: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)